# Can we have multiple tensor flow versions on Mac?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I am using Mac. I am wondering is it possible to have 2 versions of tensor flow co-existing in my computer? I pip installed tensorflow-1.13 and tensor flow-1.8 through two python virtual env. However, there seem to be some problems ...

How do I find out the corresponding c++ tensor flow library in my Mac? Where are they installed? Thanks!

Comment: usually virtual environments should be the way to go with installing two versions of the same package at once. What issue are you facing with that?

Comment: F tensorflow/stream_executor/host/host_platform.cc:97] Non-OK-status: gpu::MultiPlatformManager::RegisterPlatform(std::move(platform)) status: Internal: platform is already registered with name: "Host".  The error seems to be in cpp side ...

Comment: Perhaps you may want to edit that into the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with virtual environments: each virtual environment will contain a different version of TensorFlow, and you can switch from one to the other easily. There are many solutions to create virtual environments, but some of the most popular are:

- conda
- virtualenv
- pipenv

[Conda](https://conda.io/en/latest/) is a general-purpose, cross-platform package manager, mostly used with Python, but it can also install many other software packages. A conda environment includes everything, including Python itself, and the system binaries for the libraries you use. So you can have different conda environments with different versions of Python, and different versions of every package you want, including TensorFlow, and any C++ library your code relies on. You can install Anaconda, which is a bundle that includes Conda + Python + many scientific libraries. Or you can install miniconda which includes the bare minimum to run conda.

[Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) is a python library which allows you to create virtual environments strictly for Python.

[pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/) is also a python library that seems to be gaining a lot of momentum right now, and includes a lot of the functionality of virtualenv.

If you are a beginner, I would recommend going with conda. You will usually run into less issues.

First, download and install either [Anaconda or Miniconda](https://www.anaconda.com/).

Next, create a virtual environment:

```
conda create --name myenv
```

Then activate this virtual environment:

```
conda activate myenv
```

Now you can install all the libraries you need:

```
conda install whatever-library-you-need
```

However, not all libraries are available in conda. For example, TensorFlow 2.0 is not there yet (as of May 13th 2019). But that's okay, you can also use pip!

```
pip install --pre tensorflow
```

This will install TF 2.0 alpha.

You can then create another environment and install a different version of TF.

You can read more about the interaction between Conda and Pip [on the web](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/), but the short story is that they work well together as long as you use pip last. In short, install everything you can with conda, and finish with pip.